# Table border error

Tags: tables, border

Why I don't get the correct border in this table?

[image]

This is my code:

```
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    %\extrarowsep=_3pt^3pt
    \begin{tabu}to\linewidth{|[2pt gray]l|c|c|c|[1.5pt gray]}
    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-

            \bfseries something & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{something} \\

            \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
            \textbf{something} & \textbf{something} & \textbf{something} & \textbf{something} \\
            \hline

            \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
            something & something & something & something \\
            \hline

            \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
            something & something & something & something \\
            \hline

            \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
            something & something & something & something \\
            \hline

            \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
            something & something & something & something \\
            \hline

            \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
            \end{tabu}%
    \caption{something}
    \label{tab:something}%
    \end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post working documents, not just fragments!

Comment: Have you considered to get rid of theese table lines?  The table will be mutch better than your "excel-mode" table ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 
            `\multicolumn{3}{c|[1.5pt gray]}{something}`

i.e. you have to repeat the width of the last `|` statement as well in a `\multicolumn` command, otherwise, the standard width of `|` will be used!

`\multicolumn` is a 'special' command, that overrules the column specifications made in `tabu` (or `tabular`) -- it does not use the `|[1.5pt gray]` specification if not explicitly forced to do so.

In addition: There are too much lines anyway!

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    %\extrarowsep=_3pt^3pt
    \begin{tabu}to\linewidth{|[2pt gray]l|c|c|c|[1.5pt gray]}
    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-

    \bfseries something & \multicolumn{3}{c|[1.5pt gray]}{something} \\

    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
    \textbf{something} & \textbf{something} & \textbf{something} & \textbf{something} \\
    \hline

    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
    something & something & something & something \\
    \hline

    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
    something & something & something & something \\
    \hline

    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
    something & something & something & something \\
    \hline

    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
    something & something & something & something \\
    \hline

    \tabucline[1.5pt gray]-
  \end{tabu}%
  \caption{something}
  \label{tab:something}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]